# Nested for loops without initialisation statement in the inner loop prevents the outer loop from looping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested, initialization

```js
var i = 0,
  j = 0,
  count = 0;
for (; i < 3; i++) {
  for (; j < 3; j++) {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Why am i getting 3 instead of 9, I clearly understand that it depends on whether I insert initialization statement j=0 inside the inner loop or not , i need to know how is the flow control happening please?

Comment: "it only depends on whether I insert initialization statement j=0 ..." - what do you think the value of `j` is if you **don't** do that?

Comment: Try to print `i` and `j` on every iteration and see for yourself

Comment: Your inner loop runs only for `i = 0` and after that the code doesn't reach the inner loop as your `j` becomes 3 only at the first iteration of the outer loop

Comment: declare your variables in the loops, not only does that fix your issue, it's better practice for readability even if it does work, not even going into scoping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` is never being re-initialized, due to it being declared and initialized in the outer scope, not the scope created by the for-loop.

So to describe the flow of data to the point where `j` will never change:

```
i = 0
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
i = 1
```

At this point, `j` is still 3, so the nested for loop never evaluates its scoped statement, so then `i` continues incrementing to to 3 and the loops end. Your count is now still 3. The way a for loop is traditionally constructed is by having three parts as part:

1. Initialize iterator, which is usually a number starting at 0 (but it doesn't have to be, there are plenty of use-cases where another starting point is preferred)
2. The guard condition, basically "evaluate me until a condition is met"
3. The statement to run after every evaluation, usually incrementing or decrementing your iterator

I took some liberty with calling `i` and `j` iterators, as that's a loaded term but it's as good a term as any in a simple example.

So in short, by not re-initializing `j`, it keeps the last assigned value from the previous evaluation of the outer for loop.

Comment: i get it now , should i delete this post

Comment: Nah, leave it up, if you're happy with my answer (or other answers) and it solves your problem, you can accept it. As to why deleting answers is generally not a good thing: you asked a question which might now be obvious to you but other people might find it and the answers useful. Deleting a post is something you'd do on a forum, but not on a Q & A site.

Comment: This is a very clear answer and I'm not trying to nit-pick, but for clarity for future readers loops do not have their own scopes; j is just not being reset between iterations of the outer loop.